# NavigationService

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How can I get pointer of page from object of my class?

So, I have this code:

```
        <controls:PivotItem Header="Today">
            <Grid>
                <ScrollViewer Height="520" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <local:Fixtures Adress="..." Clubs="..."/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>
```

And I need make NavigationService.GoBack() in exception handler in my class Fixtures.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(App.Current as App).RootFrame.GoBack()
```